# Getting null pointer exception during unit testing in roboelectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I have button click listener on whose click fragment get replaced,and passes argument on next fragment.
 Code:-

```
 Fragment fragment = new CustomList();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("fragment", "Custom");
            args.putSerializable("productBean", productBean);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Written test case for button click:-

```
Button custom_btn = (Button) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.custom_btn);
             custom_btn.performClick();
```

But on execution of test cases,It shows null pointer exception when getArguments on CustomList() fragment.

```
productsBean = (ProductsBean) getArguments().getSerializable("productsBean");
```

Comment: Its productBean in the code,by mistake pasted wrong code here.Sorry.Any more suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try change this code:

```
productsBean = (ProductsBean) getArguments().getSerializable("productsBean");
```

to this

```
productsBean = (ProductsBean) getArguments().getSerializable("productBean");
```

As you can see, you are adding to the bundle the tag **"productBean"**, but when you try to get it you are using the tag **"productsBean"**, where you added the "s" charachter.

I would start with that change.

Comment: I would say - Good catch!

Comment: Its productBean in the code,by mistake pasted wrong code here.Sorry.Any more suggestion @niarb

Comment: Hi @ShivamKapoor, where are you invoking the getArguments? inside wich method of the fragment cycle? Btw, you should make some previous null check verification, to prevent the NPE, like this: 

Bundle arguments = getArguments();
if (arguments != null)
{
    // then you have arguments
} else {
    // no arguments supplied...
}

Comment: I have tried this,but getting null. So else statement gets called.As i am new to roboelectric.I am not able to understand that I am running ProductMenuTest but why it calls ProductMenu. As i have replace the fragment in Test classes.

Comment: I came to know,why it is calling ProductMenu.But why throwing null pointer exception in ProductMenu getArgument().Even I have tried changing code but still not find any solution